# Can any one relate HTTPS with real life example?

Tags: php, http, https

I read about HTTP and HTTPS. Also understand the procedure. But looking for the scenario and solution applied on real life. So that it would be more clear to understand the benefits of both.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [tag:real-time]. Don't tag indiscriminately, and don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is like a postcard: it an be read or modified by somebody else than the emitter or the receiver.

HTTPS is like a letter with a letter with a wax seal: it can't be modified without somebody notice it. And even better, it can only be read by the receiver.

You don't send postcards with your password on it.

The advantages of https for the client:

- You have a strong confidence of who send the data (authentification)
- The data cannot be modified between you and the server
- Nobody in the network can read what the server sent you
- The data you send to the server can only be read by the server and cannot be modified

The advantages of https for the server:

- Nobody else than the client can read your answer
- Your answer cannot be modified before it arrived to the client

Comment: I didn't get your your point with HTTPS, as any one can remove wax and modified letter. So how it would be secure?

Comment: I mean if somebody really wants to modify the postcard they will surely notice wax seal letter too.

Comment: You can open a wax letter and modify it, but you can't close it again without anybody noticing.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP traffic is unencrypted and can be read by any intermediary, i.e. any technical infrastructure such as routers through which it passes. As an example, when you are surfing the Web in a corporate network, the admins can see the content of any pages you view.

HTTPS is encrypted. Only the recipient can read the sent data. To all intermediaries the data only looks like random noise. Here the admin of the corporate network knows which pages you accessed, but not what they contain.